# NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle display issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The issue i am facing is very strange for me, search google for a fix but not getting any related solutions.

Issue --
I am sending push notification from Firebase panel using Cloud Messaging. When the app is open then I am able to view the notification with the small logo, title, content text and big image.

But when the app is closed then the received notification shows only small logo, title and content text. Big image is not displaying.

What may be the issue?

I am sending the code snippet i am using --

```
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bpStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
bpStyle.bigPicture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vm_notification_banner)).build();

mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vswhitenoti)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vswhitenoti))
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
                    .setStyle(bpStyle);

            mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small detail you missed in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages).

```
App state   Notification        Data                    Both
Foreground  onMessageReceived   onMessageReceived       onMessageReceived
Background  System tray         onMessageReceived       Notification: system tray
```

Your message is sent to the system tray on background instead of onMessageReceived, this is why you are not seeing your BigImageStyle.

If you want a concise and direct control everytime, use data notifications.

Comment: ya just now i got the same answer in google also. Thanks for the help. Now BigImage is getting displayed.